# nginx subdomain not redirecting to desired port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a requirement where I need to redirect subdomain to admin panel and 
domain to front facing part of site. I have created subdoamin in godaddy and 
used nginx on google compute engine. 
here are nginx conf settings which I am using:

Subdomain Rule

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name admin.example.com;

   root /var/www/html;
   index index.html;


   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
   }
}
```

Main Site Rule

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;


   server_name example.com;

   root /var/www/html;
   index index.html;


   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

both subdomain rule and main site rule are in file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

The problem is, both "example.com" and "admin.example.com" goes to "example.com".

I think, I did lot of googling but did not get solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your subdomain and Main site rule are same.

```
root /var/www/html;
index index.html;
```

You can solve this problem by making another directory and subdomain conf:

```
root /var/www/site2/html;
index index.html
```

Comment: but server_name is different, and for subdomain I am redirecting using proxy_pass, why then root setting will be used? still I checked by changing it, it did not work.

Comment: If you are redirecting by proxy pass you have to remove root and index line in your subdomain conf.

Comment: are you changed subdomain conf

Comment: Clear your browser cache and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make your subdomain conf file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```